# Not a valid result with a checkBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I try to use `CheckBox` in my app. The status of `checkBox`(checked/uncheked), I use in `putExtra` and then in next activity, depending on the result I send a `query` to `database`. The problem is with multiply check.

```
public class Myactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

CheckBox mCheck1;
CheckBox mCheck2;
CheckBox mCheck3;
ImageButton mImageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);

    mImageButton = findViewById(R.id.button_ok_option);
    mCheck1 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    mCheck2 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    mCheck3 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Choose_meet_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("1", mCheck1.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("2", ((mCheck1.isChecked()) && (mCheck2.isChecked()));
    intent.putExtra("3", mCheck2.isChecked());
    startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

For example, if I use mCheck1 - in database searching results with `"colour":"red"`,mCheck2 - `"size":"big"`. When I press the Check1 - all good, all results with `"red"` come to me. And the same positive result with mCheck2, that is, under any single condition. But when I pressed mCheck1 && mCheck2 - all results with color:`"red"`, even if `"size"` not `"big"` come back to me. What is wrong?

**EDITED:**
Choose_meet_activity.class:

```
public class Choose_meet_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public RecyclerView mResultList;
public FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
public com.google.firebase.firestore.Query query;
public FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Places, PlaceViewHolder> firestoreRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycle_activity);
    mResultList = findViewById(R.id.list_result);

    Boolean l_check1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("1");
    Boolean l_check2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("2");
    Boolean l_check3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("3");

mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
if (l_check1) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "red");
}else if (l_check2) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "red").whereEqualTo("size", "big");
}else if (l_check3) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("size", "big");
} //...
```

Comment: This is not the error, but what is the point of `intent.putExtra("2", ((mCheck1.isChecked()) && (mCheck2.isChecked()));` when you already put the values of `mCheck` 1 and 2 in "1" and "3"? As @LucasDeMoraisCabrales said, post the code of your `Choose_meet_activity.class` (should be ChooseMeetActivity btw, to follow the naming guidelines).

Comment: You should post the Choose_meet_activity code, the error is probably there

Comment: I edited question.@Eselfar

Comment: Thanks, got it@MikeKeepsOnShine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose your if-else wisely.

```
if (l_check2) {
        query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "red").whereEqualTo("size", "big");
} 
else if (l_check1) {
        query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "red");
}
else if (l_check3) {
        query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("size", "big");
}
```

Go from multiple checked to single checked.

Comment: Thanks @buzzingsilently it works, but I didn't understand a logic of this.. And, damn, what if I have hundreds quaries, which I set in ascending order. I have 9 `checkBox` in my app. So now i need for first take variants with all 9 checked, then, when only 8 from 9 `checkboxes` cheked, then when 7 e.t.c. Do i right?

Comment: It depends on logic, Does all checkbox perform different role?, Does combinations also matters and so on. Also depends on your query, Is queries are being repeated or not.

Comment: Yes you are right, you need to take variants with all 9 checked, then, when only 8 from 9 checkboxes cheked, then when 7 e.t.c.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!